# simple : php dont show some text

Tags: php, text, show

i am new to php, just learn some technic like print, echo,and so on
i just checkout uClassify library, and have output text :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => Classify275941362830057
            [classification] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Klasifikasi] => NonOpini
                            [Nilai] => 0.121026
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Klasifikasi] => Opini
                            [Nilai] => 0.878974
                        )

                )

            [Teks] => Yg ga pake im3 pasti nyesel .. Ckckck..kasian.. #dutapku -,-
        )

)
```

if i just want to print out like this :

```
[Klasifikasi] => NonOpini
[Nilai] => 0.121026
[Klasifikasi] => Opini
[Nilai] => 0.878974
```

and this is link to original code above : https://github.com/ashwanthkumar/uClassify-PHP5/blob/master/uClassify.php

explain me, how to do that..
thx for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array[0]['classification'] as $a)
    foreach ($a as $k => $v)
        echo "[$k] => $v <br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Your Whole thing is stored in an Array named `$arr`
So you will do something like below

```
<?php

foreach($arr[0]['classification'] as $new_array) {
 foreach($new_array as $key=>$value) {
   echo "[".$key."] => ".$value."<br>";
 }
}
?>
```

Hope This Helps